# Trying to find a specific element based on a condition

Tags: r

This is my dataframe in r studio. I'm trying to find code what will produce the name of the student with he highest age.

```
students.df #Name of dataframe
  name DAD BDA gender nationality age
1  Amy  80  70      F         IRL  20
2 Bill  65  50      M          UK  21
3 Carl  50  80      M         IRL  22
```

Comment: `df$name[which.max(df$age)]`

Answer (score 1):

`as.character(subset(students.df,students.df$age==max(students.df$age))$name)`

```
library(dplyr)

students.df %>% filter(age==max(age)) %>% select(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
students.df[which.max(student.df$age),]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.